# Confidence in COBE, WMAP, and PLANCK measurements of the CMB?

Tags: error-analysis, cosmic-microwave-background

I'm heavily unfamiliar with error analysis in astrophysics and have been curious about how confident we are about the measurements of the CMB by the respective satellite missions COBE, WMAP, and then PLANCK. I had done a bit of searching around to find that it would probably be stated as a signal to noise ratio but I haven't found an exact specific value.

Comment: As currently phrased (particularly the last sentence) this sounds more like trolling than an sincere question. The existence of the CMB has been on solid footing for more than 50 years now.

Comment: @JonCuster That the CMB is on solid footing is not in question here. I'm curious about how confident they were in their analysis of it. I'm not exactly okay with the usual reply of 'its just so well supported'. Such as the case with special relativity i'd rather not have that said to me and have someone link me to a collection of experiments that support it instead (such as https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/experiments.html).

Comment: Then I would suggest editing the last sentence.

Comment: I just got rid of it. It didn't serve much of a purpose then.

Comment: For COBE, here are all their papers: https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/cobe/bibliography.cfm

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the original published analysis of the COBE experiment, the error bars in the data chart (indicating the uncertainty in the data) were narrower than the width of the (very thin) line tracing the data on the graph; there is no way that the result could have been any sort of fluke or just noise.

In any case, note that all the original as-published scientific reports (intended to be read by other specialists in the field) on these experiments contain an extensive mathematical error analysis justifying the significance of the reported results. Note also that although those error analyses are almost always omitted in articles written for the general public, to omit them from the original scientific document would make it highly unlikely that the document would be accepted for publication in the first place (i.e., no legitimate scientific publication would come within a mile of it unless it included a complete statistical analysis of experimental and instrumentation errors).

Ordinarily I would recommend that you do a search for copies of the originals to read, but I will warn you when you find them that the mathematical tools used to rigorously judge the likelihood of a signal being caused by mere noise or random chance are written entirely in the language of statistics, and without specialized knowledge of that language, you will probably not be able to decipher it.